# Synchronize AudioTrack streaming with UI for Metronome

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I'm trying to make a metronome app and I have borrowed the core code from the [BeatKeeper](https://github.com/MasterEx/BeatKeeper) app/github repo. I am having an issue trying to synchronize the UI when the metronome plays a beat. The BeatKeeper repo tries to address this problem but the solution falls short. I too have tried a couple of ways but nothing has worked.

I'm using the AudioTrack class for writing audio (it's a snare sound). The audio is imported from a wav file. Given a beat per minute, I calculate the number of snare samples that should be written and then fill the remaining samples with 0 (for silence). So for each beat I write to the AudioTrack the snare samples and then the silent samples. After writing the snare sample, I send a message (using a Handler) to the UI thread which updates a TextView of the current beat. However, the two aren't in sync.

Does anyone know how to do this? I have decompiled a few metronome apps ([Mobile Metronome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gabriel.metronome) and [Metronome Beats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andymstone.metronome)) that do this perfectly. Grepping through their code, I have found imports of AudioTrack so I am assuming this is possible with AudioTrack.

I've created a very bare bones application/github repo to share the code. The [Metronome](https://github.com/blinkmacalahan/MetronomeTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pntanasis/android/metronome/Metronome.java) class is where the magic happens. I've also created a [branch](https://github.com/blinkmacalahan/MetronomeTest/blob/Marker/app/src/main/java/pntanasis/android/metronome/Metronome.java) and have attempted using the AudioTrack's NotificationMarkerPosition for when to update the UI. Using the listener, I use the current head position and add a new marker each time the event occurs to get perpetual beat events. However, that attempt starts to drift after a few beats and gets off too. I've even attempted to account for the drift and correct it, but that doesn't work either.

I know it is usually customary to post code in a question, but a repo seemed more practical to me. If necessary though I can post code. I'd appreciate any help/suggestions or alternative to make a metronome that is synchronized with the UI.

Answer (score 0):

How about this project?
https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer

It use [Visualizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) as core.

Comment: Do you have experience with Visualizer and believe it will work for my use case or is it just a suggestion? I don't have a lot of experience with audio programming, but so far I haven't seen people using visualizer for my particular use case.

I'm up for giving it a try, but I just wanted to gauge my expectation. Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion.